# fscanf and linked list's char *

Tags: c, linux, struct, linked-list, scanf

```
struct node {
        ...
        char *name;
        ...
        struct node *next;
};
```

in recursive function:

```
head->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
if (fscanf(fp, "id\t%d\nname\t%s\nmobile\t%lld\n", &head->id, head->name, &head->mobile) > 0) {
    printf("%s\n", head->name);
```

it stores correct data...suppose...

rutvik

abhinav

but when print data...

```
printf("%d\t%s\t%lld\n", head->id, head->name, head->mobile);
```

1   rutvik  9876655433

2   ��nav   1234567789

---

Let's put char pointer aside for a while.
code works great with structure

```
struct node {
...
char name[10];
...
struct node *next;
```

};

but not when I take name **[20]**, it affects *long long mobile*'s value...
why??

Output:

1   Rutvik  9876655433

2   Abhinav 578692242758466

**578692242758466** is unexpected.

Comment: *"it stores correct data"* Judging by your output, I doubt that, starting with allocating a **single char** rather than a buffer of appropriate size for your `name` field.

Answer (score 3):

You allocate `sizeof(char)` bytes, which is one byte, big enough for a null byte at the end of the string.  You read using `%s` which is unconstrained for length.

This is a heap buffer overflow; it usually leads to unhappiness.  You need to decide how much data you are going to allocate (32, 64, 4096, some other number) of bytes, and then use a format string such as `%31s` or `%63s` or `%4095s` or whatever to read the data into it.

Don't forget to check that the allocation succeeded!

There are those who will castigate you for casting `malloc()`.  If you compile with a mode such that undeclared functions are not accepted, then there's nothing much wrong with the cast in general.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I didn't get your last point, about casting malloc().
I tried allocate 10 bytes using malloc() but it didn't work out and does formating string such as %10s really needed!

Comment: The cast issue can be ignored.  Note that if you allocate N bytes for the string, you should limit the size in `%s` to N-1 bytes (32 vs `%31s`, etc).  This is a quirk of `scanf()` et al; they use the N-1 rather than N (legacy behaviour; can't be changed now — and couldn't be changed in 1989 because of the prior art, either).

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
head->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Allocates only 1 byte memory. You need to determine a maximum size and allocate that much characters:

```
head->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXNAME);
```

Then you might as well change the struct to:

```
struct node {
        ...
        char name[MAXNAME];
        ...
        struct node *next;
};
```

A better option is to keep the struct as is, have a MAXNAME size `buffer` to read from the file with scanf, then allocate sufficient space for the name:

```
// + 1 for the null character at the end
head->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer) + 1));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, char name[10] worked. but when I user char name[20] it affects long long mobile's value... help me to understand it.